# GCP: ymal environment variable format for app engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, yaml

I'm trying to deploy my web app to App Engine in GCP. I have my API key and Client key stored in my app.yaml file. but when I try to deploy my app I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: 
>     [C:\app.yaml]
>     Value 'API-KEY' for key in EnvironmentVariables does not match expression '^(?: 
>     [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$'
>     in "C:\app.yaml", line 4, column 12

and here is my app.yaml file:

```yaml
runtime: nodejs

env: flex

env_variables:

  API-KEY: 'ExampleAPIKey'

  CLIENT_ID: 'example123-clientkey1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com'
```

I tried to remove the '' but I got the same error message. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: The dash `-` isn't accepted by the regex validation. You could replace it with an underscore `_`

Comment: Thanks, you saved me!!! I didn't see that mistake! It's working now.